# 500 error Angular4 app only on Safari

Tags: c#, ios, angular, asp.net-web-api, safari

I'm having some troubles with my angular4 app that works perfectly on Chrome, Edge and Firefox but returns error with Safari both on OSX and IOS.

All my requests get a 500 error code with this error (the backend is a C# webapi) :

> { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.", "ExceptionType":
>   "System.NullReferenceException", "StackTrace": "   at
>   A_BoardBE.SessionUtils.GetSessionGM(HttpContextBase httpContextBase,
>   IHttpRouteData route) in
>   C:\Users\Aurelien.Joly\Source\Repos\A-BoardBE\A_BoardBE\SessionUtils.cs:line
>   30\r\n   at A_BoardBE.Controllers.ProjectController.GetModelDate() in
>   C:\Users\Aurelien.Joly\Source\Repos\A-BoardBE\A_BoardBE\Controllers\ProjectController.cs:line
>   812\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

But I don't understand why this error only appears with Safari.

My package.json is :

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.3",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^5.1.2",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^9.1.0",
"@types/intro.js": "^2.4.3",
"angular2-debounce": "^1.0.3",
"angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
"angular2-notifications": "^0.5.7",
"angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
"angulartics2": "^2.3.0",
"animate.css": "3.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"chart.js": "^2.5.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"d3": "^4.8.0",
"file-droppa": "^1.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"intro.js": "^2.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.1.0",
"metismenu": "^2.5.0",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.2",
"ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
"ng2-completer": "^1.2.2",
"ng2-datepicker": "^1.8.3",
"ng2-draggable": "^0.2.1",
"ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
"ng2-handsontable": "^0.48.0",
"ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
"ng2-signalr": "^2.1.0",
"ng2-smart-table": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-toastr": "^4.0.1",
"ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
"ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.0.0",
"ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
"ngx-uploader": "^3.3.11",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"signalr": "^2.2.2",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@types/d3": "^4.8.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "~1.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^4.0.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

If you have any idea where it could come from, my polyfills seems to be ok too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand the request you are making is not correct. Debug the request and see what's happening in the controller with Quick watch option.

Comment: What is strange is that everything is going fine with other browsers ....